# How do I return a result of Nightmare to a variable?

Tags: javascript, nightmare

I'm struggling with the asynchronicity of javascript using https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare to save its scraped data to a variable.

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var nightmare = Nightmare();

var title = nightmare
    .goto('https://github.com')
    .evaluate(function () {
        return document.title;
    })
    .end()
    .then((result) => {
        // console.log(result);
    });

console.log(title);
```

The console output looks like: `Promise { <pending> }`

How do I store the result to the `title` variable before the console will log? Am I supposed to use generator functions with `yield`?

Comment: Just uncomment the line inside the `then` - you seem to already know how it works?

Comment: If you read the linked answer, you will find out that you are trying to solve the wrong thing. You cannot return a value from an asynchronous call, so "how do I return a value from an asynchronous call" is focusing on the method, when you should be asking yourself "what do I want to do with this value", as it will only be reliably available in the callback. If the answer is "print it", as @Bergi says, you already know how to do it.